# How I can start my Application when it is not running?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

Well, my question is too simple:
How I can start my Application when it is not running?

Scenarios:

- Start when boot device or auto-update app [solved with [cordova-plugin-autostart]](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/autostart/)
- Start when app is not running.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) con.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Date futureDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 86400000);
futureDate.setHours(8);
futureDate.setMinutes(0);
futureDate.setSeconds(0);
Intent intent = new Intent(con, MyAppReciever.class);

PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(con, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,futureDate.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

and then use a [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to start the app:

```
public class MyAppReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    startActivity(new Intent(context, MyAppMainActivity.class));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks too much. Can you explain me how to implement it. I assumes add AlarmManager to `java/com.myapp.ionic/MainActivity.java`

Comment: @OlafErlandsen yes you need to added there exatly and then you need to add permission to your manifest. check this example ;) https://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/
first hit on google :P

Comment: In this example, you use `Date futureDate` but when import `java.util.Date`, I cant resolve `futureDate.getTimeInMillis()`. Whats class need import???

Comment: you can use `getTIme()`
 https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime()

Comment: Because it will run after a while, check the time adjust it and check the example in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Create a service, with only function - controll if your app is running and start your app (for example with command prompt `am start -n com.example.my_app/com.example.my_app.LauncherActivity`. Start that service on device boot and keep it alive.